# How to nest a Rails application into another rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Lets say have a main app, that also has a blog, I like to keep the "blog" part of the app as a separate rails app and re-use it in other rails apps as well.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The currently popular method to do what you are trying to achieve is to use ***Engines***. Engines basically let you mount one application inside another, allowing you to do anything from add a method or two, to adding a complete blog. The [official guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) have a very nice step-by-step guide to getting started, and there are many good [unofficial guides](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails%20engines), as well. An engine basically consists of a little bit of initialization code, the application code, and a dummy application for testing and development. It might look intimidating, at first, but it's much easier than it sounds, at first. Good luck